# Angular2/Typescript/ngRx - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

In the constructor I do something like this

```
selectedDate: Object;
// construtor
this.selectedDate = {};
this.selectedDate['date'] = new Date();
this.selectedDate['pristine'] = new Date();
```

In another function which gets called on a button click I do the following:

```
this.selectedDate['date'] = new Date(this.selectedDate['pristine']);
```

And I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'date' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: can you show the `onClick` function

Comment: Are you using redux? If ```this.selectedDate``` is somehow put in an action  payload and assigned to the state in a reducer you won't be able to modify it directly without another action going through the pipeline.

Comment: Sounds like you should just define the type rather than using `Object`; at that point you might as well use `any` and be done with it. IOW, use `selectedDate: { date: Date, pristine: Date }` (or whatever your properties are).

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, I am using redux and now I understand why I am seeing this issue. Your analysis is correct, thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credits to Ryan Q:

As Ryan commented I was using ngRx in my app and I was indeed passing this.selectedDate object through an action into the store and hence I was not able to modify the object that is stored in the State.

One way to resolve this is pass a new object reference and this should resolve the issue:

```
this.store.dispatch(new settime.DateChangeAction(Object.assign({}, this.selectedDate)));
```

Answer (score 2):

@vikas' answer put me on the right track to solve a similar issue.

I'm trying to handle an upload, where I want to display the progress:
 - From the `UploadComponent`, I emit an event to the parent
 - The parent dispatch an action to the store
 - An effect catches the action, call the service to upload the file (which returns an array with two observables: `progress$` and `result$`)
 - The effect dispatch an `HttpProgress` action which contains the observable

And at this point I had a similar issue. After digging into store freeze code, a coworker and I found out that it also deep freeze the `action.payload`. And thus, passing an observable results into an error as observable state is mutated internally.

I'm **not** using the payload to keep it into the store, just so I can register to actions$ within my component so here it doesn't matter if I pass a mutable object into the payload. To avoid that error, I just wrapped the observable into a function as deep freeze do not freeze functions.